# Facebook api - very slow posting by php

Tags: php, facebook, performance, api, post

On my site users can share theirs reflinks by button. Problem is very slow posting on facebook. My code is following:

```
if (isset($_GET['error_reason']) && $_GET['error_reason'] == 'user_denied') 
{
    echo 'You must accept permissions!';
} 
else 
{
    include_once 'src/facebook.php';

    $appId = '.............';
    $secret = '............';
    $returnurl = 'http://site.pl/user/postOnFb.html'; 
    $permissions = 'publish_stream';

    //clean cache
    $_SESSION['fb_'.$appId.'_user_id'] = '';
    $_SESSION['fb_'.$appId.'_access_token'] = '';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret));
    $fbuid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($fbuid) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $status = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => 'TEST'));
            if($status)
            {
                echo 'Post was succesfully published';
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo 'Error! Try again later.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $fbloginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$returnurl, 'scope'=>$permissions));
         header('Location: '.$fbloginurl);
    }
}
```

I debugged code and '$facebook->api()' takes about 7 sec. Facebook api is so slow? Or what is wrong?

Edit:
I was debugging and I noticed function makeRequest in BaseFacebook is slow:

```
var_dump(time()); // i add this
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(time().'</br>'); // i add this
```

Output:

```
int(1387198153) int(1387198158) //5 seconds
int(1387198158) int(1387198163) //5 seconds
int(1387198164) int(1387198171) //7 seconds
```

So problem is with `curl_exec()`, but what is wrong?

Comment: Well, sometimes it is but normally it shouldn't take more then half a second. Is there some kind of loop around this code?

Comment: @MarkusKottländer No, it's all code from postOnFb.html. In debugger I see one page is long loading and $facebook->api() cause it. Maybe something can be wrong in application on facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are something problems with protocol IPv6 which Facebook use. The solve is set curl to use only ipv4.

**base_facebook.php:**

```
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE      => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4, // <-- ADD THIS LINE
  );
```